# Getting the out of range index error when trying to make a Page Tab View from API array

Tags: swift, swiftui, pagetabviewstyle

This is my Model:

```
class Api {
    func getRockets(completion: @escaping ([Rocket]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let rockets = try JSONDecoder().decode([Rocket].self, from: data!)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(rockets)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

I try to make PageTabView using elements from the API array, but my app crashes with an out of range index error.

This is the View that doesn't work properly:

```
struct TestTabViewView: View {
    @State var rockets: [Rocket] = [] //<-- The array of items from the API I use to make tabs
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                Text(rocket.name)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Api().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}

struct TestTabViewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestTabViewView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd bet that `TabView` requires you to have at least 1 view, which you won't until the API returns. What happens if you include a placeholder view instead of the `TabView` until `rockets` has elements?

Comment: @jnpdx, it sounds like a great solution, but unfortunately I don't know how to do it in this particular case. I know that it's possible to add something like 'static let example = Rocket(name: "Falcon 1")' to my Model, then add 'var rocket: Rocket' at the top of the struct of the View, and then add missing argument to the Preview of that View. I've tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Add an `if rockets.isEmpty` clause around the entire TabView and display something else if the array is empty (like a loading indicator)

Comment: Thank you, @jnpdx, it helped, but there was another problem I described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802451/how-to-delete-navbar-in-navigationview-at-all-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `TabView` inside an if-else statement, and in turn put this statement inside `NavigationView` or `Group`, and then call the `.onAppear` method for an external container (for example, `Group`), everything will work properly and there will be no an out of range index error.

```
struct TestTabViewView: View {
    @State var rockets: [Rocket] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if rockets.isEmpty {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                        Text(rocket.name)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Api().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
    }
}
```