# How to delete Navbar in NavigationView at all

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I've already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774637/getting-the-out-of-range-index-error-when-trying-to-make-a-page-tab-view-from-ap) how to get rid of an out of range index error when using **page styled TabView** when I get data from API. There I was advised to do this:

> Add an **if rockets.isEmpty** clause around the entire **TabView** and display
> something else if the array is empty (like a loading indicator)

```
// MARK: - API
class InfoApi {
    func getRockets(completion: @escaping ([RocketInfo]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let rocketsInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([RocketInfo].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(rocketsInfo)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}

// MARK: - ROCKET MODEL
struct RocketInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let country: String
}

// MARK: - CONTENT VIEW
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rockets: [RocketInfo] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if rockets.isEmpty {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    TabView {
                        ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                                        .renderingMode(.original)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(height: 190, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32)
                                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 865, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                        
                                        VStack(spacing: 40) {
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("Name")
                                                    .font(.title)
                                                Spacer()
                                                Text(rocket.name)
                                                    .font(.title)
                                            }
                                        } //: VSTACK
                                        .padding(.horizontal)
                                    } //: ZSTACK
                                } //: VSTACK
                                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            } //: SCROLL
                        } //: LOOP
                    } //: TAB
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                } //: NAVIGATION
            }
        } //: GROUP
        .onAppear {
            InfoApi().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It helped, but there was another problem. To wrap TabView in an **if-else** clause, I had to add some other View outside it (for example, **NavigationView**) and call the **onAppear** method for this View to make everything work. There was a problem with the fact that I cannot completely remove the white safe area at the top of **NavigationView**.

[That's what it looks like in the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Ymy.png)

If I wrap **TabView** in **HStack** instead of **NavigationView**, then when scrolling ScrollView to the end, I see a white bar at the very bottom, which I also don't know how to get rid of.

[This white space at the bottom of the ScrollView I was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIz4z.png)

[image: The View that I want to create]

Comment: I've left a number of possible solutions -- none are full-code since what you've included isn't a [mre], but it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it turned out that it is quite impossible to get rid of navbar if you use both TabBar and NavigationView in one View.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of potential solutions to this. All involve getting rid of the `NavigationView` since it seems that your only use for it was that you needed some sort of wrapper view.

Solution #1:
Move your `isEmpty` check inside the `TabView`

```
var body: some View {
  TabView {
    if rockets.isEmpty {
      //ProgressView
    } else {
      //your tabs
    }
  }.onAppear {
    //API call
  }
}
```

Solution #2:
Instead of `NavigationView`, wrap your content in a `Group`:

```
var body: some View {
  Group {
    if !rockets.isEmpty {
      TabView { /*...*/ }
    }
  }.onAppear {
    //API call
  }
}
```

Solution #3: call `onAppear` on the progress view when it appears

```
if rockets.isEmpty {
  ProgressView()
   .onAppear {
     //API call
   }
} else {
  TabView {
    //tab content
  }
}
```

---

Edit: complete example with mocked objects/API

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    @State var rockets: [RocketInfo] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if rockets.isEmpty {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    TabView {
                        
                        ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                            Text(rocket.title)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            InfoApi().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answers) Each of your solutions work until I set a paged style to my TabView.

Comment: And what happens then?

Comment: For example, I use your solution #3.
It works, I can switch between tabs, but when I add **.tabViewStyle(.page)** to my TabView, I see the ProgressView() screen all the time and nothing else happens.

Comment: That seems like it would be an unusual and unlikely situation. Are you sure you're putting `.tabViewStyle(.page)` in the right place (ie attached to the `TabView` closure)? If so, can you update your original question with the code you've tried (ideally with everything unnecessary removed)?

Comment: Sure, just did it.

Comment: Can you post your attempt at solution #1?

Comment: Did it. Have the same problem. I see the ProgressView() screen all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run your code because it's missing too many types, but I did manage to see the same issue with solution #1 when I created my own minimal example. See the update to my post -- it's solution 3 and my self contained minimal example proves it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried it and it worked. But I realised why it didn't work with my code – NavigationView. If you try to add NavigationView inside the TabView, you'll face the error I was talking about. Unfortunately, in my project I have to use NavigationView, because I have NavigationLink button that opens another View.
Sadly, the very first code where I used NavigationView instead of Group, like you did in your solution, remains the only solution close to what I have to do to pass my project and try to get an internship.

Comment: I've updated my example to include a `NavigationView`. Still works for me (note that I put it *outside* of the `TabView` -- putting in *inside* like you have would be a very unusual and uncommon design decision on iOS -- I've never seen an app do that).

Comment: By the way, this sort of confusion is why you should really try to include a [mre] -- otherwise, you run the risk of a solution not working for you because your needs are different than what the answerer can infer from incomplete code.

Comment: The updated code in your question works fine for me. If it doesn't for you, can you list what device/simulator and iOS version?

Comment: I updated my code to make it a minimal reproducible example. I tried to use NavigationView as you showed and the result looks the same as when I used NavigationView as a wrapper for if-else statement. I mean, the white stripe on top is still in place, and I don't understand how to get rid of it. At the end of my question, I added a link to the image of how I want the screen of my application to look like, that is, the picture in the View would be touched the top of the screen.

Comment: Yeah, without both a `TabView` *and* `NavigationView` I agree that it seems challenging to get that top image to ignore the safe area